# Memoryless property of geometric distribution (SOA EXAM P)

Tags: probability

Patients in a study are tested for sleep apnea, one at a time, until a patient is found to have this disease. Each patient independently has the same probability of having sleep apnea. Let r represent the probability that at least four patients are tested.
Determine the probability that at least twelve patients are tested given that at least four patients are tested.

Correct answer : $r^{8/3}$

My Solution:
Let X ~ geom(p).

$P(X\geq 4) = 1-P(X < 4) = 1 - P(X \leq 3) =$ by CDF of geom$=  1- (1-(1-p)^3) = r \rightarrow (1-p) = r^{1/3}$

Find $P(X\geq 12 | X \geq 4) = $ memoryless property of geom distr = $P(X \geq 8) = 1-P(X < 8) = 1-P(X \leq 7) = $ by CDF of geom $ = 1-(1-(1-p)^7) = (1-p)^7 = r^{7/3}$

What am I doing wrong? There seems to be another solution in reddit here, but I am wondering what is wrong with my reasoning because I don't see it. 
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/bxu13h/discrete_random_variables_conditional_probability/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted is correct.
There is a small mistake in your answer, when you apply the memoryless property:

If you look carefully the memory less property, you see that the formula is:
$$P(X\ge t+s |X\color{red}{>}s)=P(X\ge t)$$
Hence, you have to replace $\ge4$ with $>3$ and you get your answer.

Comment: I thougth about that, but what about here : http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/GeometricF.pdf? and meanwhile wikipedia only uses strict inequalities ? I'm confused which one is right

Comment: In this link (what’s that) they are using a different, riscaled, pcf: they start from 0. Hence you should pay attention to the formulae you use. Anyway, if you look and use the the second to last step $(1-p)^s$ you get your answer. But I would stick with one geometric distribution, preferably the one on the positive integer (that counts the number of trials and not of failures)

Comment: ok so should I just go with wikipedia and stick with strict inequalities? or the one you wrote?

Comment: I’m telling you to be consistent: if you work with your file, i.e. with that pdf and pcf, than use the related memory less property. If you work with Wikipedia pcf (so distribution on the positive integers), use the relate property. Do not mix formulae that come from different assumptions!